# Wordpress: How to get the link of a particular category

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Okay, on my blog I have four categories that the user can click to. Management, Industry News, Productivity etc.

Here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9GuR.jpg

**Requirement**: I need to find a way using php to link to each category page.

```
        <div class="categories-section">
        <div class="category">
        <?php 
            $categories = get_categories();
            foreach ($categories as $cat) {
                if($cat->cat_name = 'MANAGEMENT') {
                 $category_link = get_category_link($cat->cat_ID);
                }

            }
        ?>

            <a href="#"><img class="category-icon" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/img/desktop/images/category-icon-1.jpg">
            <h3> INDUSTRY NEWS</h3></a>
        </div>
        <div class="category">
            <a href="<?php echo $category_link; ?>"><img class="category-icon" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/img/desktop/images/category-icon-2.jpg">
            <h3> MANAGEMENT</h3></a>
        </div>
        <div class="category">
            <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/category/PRODUCTIVITY/"><img class="category-icon" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/img/desktop/images/category-icon-1.jpg">
            <h3> PRODUCTIVITY</h3></a>
        </div>
        <div class="category">
            <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/category/PERSONAL-DEVELOPEMENT/"><img class="category-icon" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/img/desktop/images/category-icon-2.jpg">
            <h3> PERSONAL DEVELOPEMENT</h3></a>
        </div>          
    </div>
```

Problem: The page css is breaking and it's not working, currently the only way I can to link to category is to hard code it.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an equal sign (`=`) in the `if`-condition in your `foreach`.

```
if ($cat->cat_name == 'MANAGEMENT') {
    $category_link = get_category_link($cat->cat_ID);
    break;
}
```

You should also `break` after the result has been found so you don't loop over the other categories.

**Update:**
I'm not sure if there is a better function in Wordpress to do this, but you could save all links in an associative array to get all links at once.

```
$wp_categories = get_categories();
$categories = [];
foreach ($wp_categories as $cat)
    $categories[$cat->cat_name] = get_category_link($cat->cat_ID);
```

Now you can do the following:

```
// Management link:
echo $categories['MANAGEMENT'];
```

Comment: is there a better way then to have 4 different for loops for each link?

Comment: I have added an update that maps all links for easy use.